# Why does QlikView keep crashing when I try to load my data?

Tags: python, excel, qlikview

I have data in an excel spreadsheet (*.xlsx) that consists of 1,213 rows of sensitive information (so, I'm sorry I can't share the data) and 35 columns. Every entry is a string (I don't know if that is screwing it up or not). The first row is the column names and I've never had a problem importing it with the column names embedded before (it's just easier to click that they're embedded so I don't have to name every column by hand). I put the path to the data in the quick start wizard and hit the next button and it doesn't do anything. I hit it again and it turns the mouse into the loader as if it's loading. I've waited for it for 15 minutes before, but every time I click on QlikView the program just crashes.

I have a deadline I have to meet here and I can't afford to not finish this project. It's extremely important that I get it working.

Just as a NB, I used Python to merge two Excel spreadsheets together so I don't know if that may be what's causing the problem either. I can open the file perfectly fine in Excel though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the walkthrough when creating a new file when I should have just made a script. First click on `edit script` in the menu bar. Click `Table Files...`. Choose your file, then make sure that the `Labels` section has `Embedded Labels` in the dropdown. It will create a query like the following-

```
LOAD [Resource name], 
     [Employee ID], 
     Vertical, 
     [Contract Type *], 
     Notes
FROM
[D:\path\to\file\*.xlsx]
(ooxml, embedded labels, table is Sheet1);
```

That's one part of the solution, but then I ran into a new problem. It said that it was able to fetch all of the rows, but when I started making the charts and graphs it was only showing 6 data points. I recreated the file, did exactly what I did above but also added the transformation step. Now the problem is solved.

Comment: The line [Contract Type *] looks odd to me unless that is the exact name in your xlsx. Also are there not perhaps more than one xlsx in that folder location because the behaviour you describe is what indicative of QlikView trying to create too many Syn keys. Can you load the same data through the debuggger with only 10 lines and see the results?

Answer (score 0):

I have had QlikView crash when importing an Excel spreadsheet that was exported with the SQuirreL SQL client (from a Firebird database). Opening the spreadsheet in Excel, and saving it again solved the problem.

I know that this is no longer relevant to your problem, but hopefully it can help someone with a similarly appearing issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you do not include a 'header is 0 lines,' which could be cauing an issue?

Follows a snippet from my standard Excel file import - just the FROM section. My setup is done through variables but they follow this form:

```
Set vTableW = 'WIP Metrics' ;
Set vPathData = '..\Raw Data Reports\' ;
Set vFile08 = 'Misc Transactions VCB*.xlsx' ;
Set vHeader08 = 2 ;
Set vSheet08 = 'Misc Trans' ;
Set vWhere08 = ( Len(Trim([Date Received])) > 0 
                    And Len(Trim([Lot Number])) > 0 
                        And Len(Trim([Y/N])) > 0 
                            And Len(Trim([Initials])) > 0 ) ;


'$(vTableW)':
Load
    AutoNumber(RowNo(), 1) As [_Load WIPWO ID],
    ...
    additional columns
    ...
    If(IsNull([Comments]), '', Trim([Comments])) As [VCB Comments]
From
'$(vPathData)$(vFile08)'
(ooxml, embedded labels, header is $(#vHeader08) lines, table is '$(vSheet08)')
Where($(vWhere08)) ;
```

Regarding the point made above relating to syn keys, add the line

```
Exit Script ;
```

Before your import to check load is OK to that point. Then move it immediately after the Excel load and repeat. Use the debug facility in the Load Script process.

Hope this helps!